# Why required message in radio button irregular (jquery validation)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript code is like this:

```
...

$('#mailer').validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email_address: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        request: {
            required: true
        },
        gender: {
            required: true
        }
    },
...
```

Demo and complete code is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/2yXsL/549/

When gender is not selected and the submit button is clicked, there is a "field required" message. But the message is irregular. The message should appear at the leftmost section, such as "field required" messages for the text fields.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `errorPlacement` option. Try adding this to your options:

```
    errorPlacement :function(error,element){
      switch(element.attr('name')) {
        case 'gender':
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            break;
        default:
            error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
```

Here's an amended fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/551/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
label.error {
  float: right;
}
```

You can see that it works using your modified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/550/